# Why doesn't this CompiledQuery give a performance improvement?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, compiled-query

I am trying to speed up an often used query. Using a `CompiledQuery` seemed to be the answer. But when I tried the compiled version, there was no difference in performance between the compiled and non-compiled versions.

Can someone please tell me why using `Queries.FindTradeByTradeTagCompiled` is not faster than using `Queries.FindTradeByTradeTag`?

```
static class Queries
{
    // Pre-compiled query, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297
    private static readonly Func<MyEntities, int, IQueryable<Trade>> mCompiledFindTradeQuery =
        CompiledQuery.Compile<MyEntities, int, IQueryable<Trade>>(
            (entities, tag) => from trade in entities.TradeSet
                               where trade.trade_tag == tag
                               select trade);

    public static Trade FindTradeByTradeTagCompiled(MyEntities entities, int tag)
    {
        IQueryable<Trade> tradeQuery = mCompiledFindTradeQuery(entities, tag);

        return tradeQuery.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static Trade FindTradeByTradeTag(MyEntities entities, int tag)
    {
        IQueryable<Trade> tradeQuery = from trade in entities.TradeSet
                                       where trade.trade_tag == tag
                                       select trade;

        return tradeQuery.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: This link may help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336024.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to orandov, I found the answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336024.aspx) (at the end). If you make **any** changes to the query, the precompiled statement is discarded. In my case, `FirstOrDefault()` was changing the underlying query.

Solution was to call `AsEnumerable()` on the query first. By calling `AsEnumerable()` the precompiled query was protected, and `FirstOrDefault()` was executed locally on the results (it was called against `Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` rather than `Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault`).

Net result: execution time was reduced from 45ms to 4ms. 11x faster.

```
public static Trade FindTradeByTradeTagCompiled(MyEntities entities, int tag)
{
    IQueryable<Trade> tradeQuery = mCompiledFindTradeQuery(entities, tag);

    return tradeQuery.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than `AsEnumerable` (which won't limit the results at the database), have you tried:

```
// Pre-compiled query, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297
private static readonly Func<MyEntities, int, IQueryable<Trade>> mCompiledFindTradeQuery =
    CompiledQuery.Compile<MyEntities, int, IQueryable<Trade>>(
        (entities, tag) => (from trade in entities.TradeSet
                           where trade.trade_tag == tag
                           select trade).Take(1));
```

Answer (score 4):

Queries are always "compiled" it's just that if you don't use the `CompiledQuery` then it'll be compiled on-demand. Also, the `CompiledQuery` is only compiled the first time it's executed anyway (the difference being that a `CompiledQuery` is only compiled once, whereas the 'regular' way will be compiled each time). For such a simple query like the one you've got, the overhead of compiling is probably quite small.

Do you have an index on the `trade_tag` field? That'll provide you with the biggest performance increase.

Comment: Thank you for your general comments, but you have not answered the question at all. Yes, there is an index on trade_tag. If the query is called 100,000 times (as it will be), the overhead is not "quite small".

Comment: I think this answers the question very well, even if the FirstOrDefault was the actual problem. The question never asked why there's no performance improvement in 100,000 calls - it was just why is the compiled not faster than the not compiled. Thus the answer "they are actually both compiled" is quite fitting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning IQueryable, just set up the compiled query to return the single Trade object directly.  This is a lot cleaner code than the previous solutions.

```
// Pre-compiled query, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297
private static readonly Func<MyEntities, int, Trade> mCompiledFindTradeQuery =
    CompiledQuery.Compile<MyEntities, int, Trade>(
        (entities, tag) => (from trade in entities.TradeSet
                           where trade.trade_tag == tag
                           select trade).FirstOrDefault() );

public static Trade FindTradeByTradeTagCompiled(MyEntities entities, int tag)
{
    return mCompiledFindTradeQuery(entities, tag);
}
```

Another example is here:
[Linq to SQL to Linq compiled performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182926/linq-to-sql-to-linq-compiled-performance)